# CSS flex. Как прижать только один дочерний элемент к краю

Tags: css, позиционирование

Есть блок с несколькими дочерними элементами, и требуется, чтобы один был прижат к правому краю, а остальные к левому.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.righted {
  order: 999;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child righted">child1</div>
  <div class="child">child2</div>
  <div class="child">child3</div>
  <div class="child">child4</div>
</div>
```

[Пример на Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxbjvR)

Answer (score 6):

Для того чтобы прижать елемент к краю эму нужно задать `margin-left:auto`. Если елемент который вы хотите прижать не крайний с права установите `order:2` для этого елемента.

Comment: Очень информативно, спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: @Дмитрий Мирошниченко === шикарное решение !!!